# One object in class overwriting the other

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a module that contains a class with methods that return various information about a given DNA sequence. I want to write another module with a class that can compare the information from two sequences. Here is what I have.

```
import genomeAnalyzer as g

class GenomePair:

    def __init__(self, gene_1, gene_2):
            self.gene_1 = g.Genome(gene_1)
            self.gene_2 = g.Genome(gene_2)

    def compareGC(self):
            print(self.gene_1.gcComp())
            print(self.gene_2.gcComp())



GenomePair_obj = GenomePair("testTiny.fa", "haloVolc1_1-genes.fa")
GenomePair_obj.compareGC()
```

And here is a snippet of Genome class which itself uses another module.

```
import sequenceAnalysis as seq 

class Genome:

    def __init__(self, file):
        """
        Separates sequence data from header data in the given FASTA file,
        creates a NucParams object and calls the codonComposition method
        to populate the codon dictionary.       
        """
        self.file = file
        self.fasta = seq.FastAreader(self.file)
        sequence = ""
        for pair in self.fasta.readFasta(): 
            DNA = pair[1]
            sequence += DNA
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.DNA_obj = seq.NucParams(self.sequence)
        seq.NucParams.codonComposition(self) #Necessary?

    def gcComp(self):
        sum = seq.NucParams.nucCount(self)
        GC_count = 0
        for nuc in ['G', 'C']:
            GC_count += seq.NucParams.nuc_freq[nuc]
        GC_comp = ((GC_count / sum) * 100)
        return GC_comp
```

And NucParams:

```
class NucParams:

    rnaCodonTable = {
    # RNA codon table
    # U
    'UUU': 'F', 'UCU': 'S', 'UAU': 'Y', 'UGU': 'C', # UxU
    'UUC': 'F', 'UCC': 'S', 'UAC': 'Y', 'UGC': 'C', # UxC
    'UUA': 'L', 'UCA': 'S', 'UAA': '-', 'UGA': '-', # UxA
    'UUG': 'L', 'UCG': 'S', 'UAG': '-', 'UGG': 'W', # UxG
    # C
    'CUU': 'L', 'CCU': 'P', 'CAU': 'H', 'CGU': 'R', # CxU
    'CUC': 'L', 'CCC': 'P', 'CAC': 'H', 'CGC': 'R', # CxC
    'CUA': 'L', 'CCA': 'P', 'CAA': 'Q', 'CGA': 'R', # CxA
    'CUG': 'L', 'CCG': 'P', 'CAG': 'Q', 'CGG': 'R', # CxG
    # A
    'AUU': 'I', 'ACU': 'T', 'AAU': 'N', 'AGU': 'S', # AxU
    'AUC': 'I', 'ACC': 'T', 'AAC': 'N', 'AGC': 'S', # AxC
    'AUA': 'I', 'ACA': 'T', 'AAA': 'K', 'AGA': 'R', # AxA
    'AUG': 'M', 'ACG': 'T', 'AAG': 'K', 'AGG': 'R', # AxG
    # G
    'GUU': 'V', 'GCU': 'A', 'GAU': 'D', 'GGU': 'G', # GxU
    'GUC': 'V', 'GCC': 'A', 'GAC': 'D', 'GGC': 'G', # GxC
    'GUA': 'V', 'GCA': 'A', 'GAA': 'E', 'GGA': 'G', # GxA
    'GUG': 'V', 'GCG': 'A', 'GAG': 'E', 'GGG': 'G'  # GxG
    }
    dnaCodonTable = {key.replace('U','T'):value for key, value in rnaCodonTable.items()}
    DNA_codon_freq = {}
    RNA_codon_freq = {}
    nuc_freq = {'A':0, 'T':0, 'G':0, 'C':0, 'U':0, 'N':0}
    aa_dic = {}
    is_DNA = True

    def __init__ (self, sequence):
        for i in NucParams.dnaCodonTable: 
            NucParams.DNA_codon_freq[i] = 0
        for i in NucParams.rnaCodonTable:
            NucParams.RNA_codon_freq[i] = 0
        self.sequence = sequence
        NucParams.addSequence(self,self.sequence)

    def addSequence (self, thisSequence):
        s = ''.join(thisSequence).split()
        s = ''.join(s).upper()
        clean_seq = ""
        if 'U' in s:
            NucParams.is_DNA = False
        for nuc in s:
            if nuc in ['A', 'T', 'G', 'C', 'U', 'N']:
                clean_seq += nuc
                NucParams.nuc_freq[nuc] += 1
        self.nuc_string = clean_seq
        start, stop = 0, 3
        codon_count = len(self.nuc_string) // 3
        for i in range(codon_count):
            codon = self.nuc_string[start:stop]
            if 'N' in codon:
                pass
            elif NucParams.is_DNA == True:
                NucParams.DNA_codon_freq[codon] += 1
            elif NucParams.is_DNA == False:
                NucParams.RNA_codon_freq[codon] += 1
            start += 3
            stop += 3

    def aaComposition(self):
        if NucParams.is_DNA:
            freq = NucParams.DNA_codon_freq
            dic = NucParams.dnaCodonTable
        else:
            freq = NucParams.RNA_codon_freq
            dic = NucParams.rnaCodonTable
        for i in dic:
            x = dic.get(i)
            NucParams.aa_dic[x] = 0
        for codon in freq: 
            NucParams.aa_dic[dic[codon]] += freq[codon]
        return NucParams.aa_dic

    def nucComposition(self):
        return NucParams.nuc_freq

    def codonComposition(self): #Must output as RNA codon freq regardless of input
        if NucParams.is_DNA == False:
            return NucParams.RNA_codon_freq
        else:
            NucParams.RNA_codon_freq = {key.replace('T','U'):value for key, value in NucParams.DNA_codon_freq.items()}
            return NucParams.RNA_codon_freq 

    def nucCount(self):
        sum = 0
        for i in NucParams.nuc_freq:
            sum += NucParams.nuc_freq[i]
        return sum
```

The method `gcComp()` returns a number from 0-100 representing the percentage of Gs or Cs in the sequence.

When I comment out the `self.gene_2` line in `__init__` and the corresponding print line it prints a GC comp of 50.0. When I do the same for `self.gene_1` I get a GC comp of 49.3. But when both are declared they both hold the value 49.3.

Why when I create a second object does it overwrite the first? They have different names don't they?

Comment: How is your `Genome` class implemented? It sounds like it may be using a class variable rather than an instance variable somewhere, but since you haven't shown its code, I can't be sure.

Comment: @Sam: The code from seq.NucParams will be necessary, too. How is nuc_freq initialized?

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible problems concerning object oriented programming and the difference between class and object variables.

E.g. in the class `seq.NucParams`:

```
def nucComposition(self):
    return NucParams.nuc_freq
```

This is returning the static (so class wide, in your case program wide) value of nuc_freq - NOT the `nuc_freq` of the object (which is `self.nuc_freq`).

Another example:

In `Genome.__init__` you assign `self.DNA_obj` an NucParams instance:

```
self.DNA_obj = seq.NucParams(self.sequence)
```

But you won't use it anymore in the rest of your code. It seems you're using seq.NucParams as a class with static functions instead of an object with methods.

I assume in `gcComp()` you have to use

```
sum = self.DNA_obj.nucCount()       # instead of sum = seq.NucParams.nucCount(self)
```

and

```
GC_count += self.DNA_obj.nuc_freq[nuc]     # instead of GC_count += seq.NucParams.nuc_freq[nuc]
```

IMHO you have to correct all these wrong usages of class variables by the usage of object (instance) variables.

Comment: ...and I suppose `seq.NucParams.codonComposition(self)` has to be `self.DNA_obj.codonComposition()`

Comment: I tried this, the Genome class still works as before but the problem remains in GenomePair.

Comment: I updated my answer. The main problem is in `seq.NucParams` and the possibly wrong usage of class variables (e.g. `NucParams.nuc_freq`) instead of object variables (e.g. `self.nuc_freq`)

Comment: It turns out I was mistaken, It isn't overwriting it but it seems to be giving a value created by a combination of the two. Somehow both objects are using the same dictionary...

Comment: @Sam: That's right. And the 'somehow' is what I tried to show with my answer.

Comment: I fixed the issue and in hindsight you were on the right track but the main issue wasn't how I was calling the dictionaries but their location. I instantiated them in the class rather than in the __init__ method. Thanks anyways.